# Weird order of execution in Qt C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, std

Apologies if this has been asked before but I could not find any answers. If someone can enlighten me what is going on here?

I was playing around with Qt and standard c++. So the payground code below didn't do what I expected. Is that related QCoreApplication queue? I expected the sequence of **1 2 3 4 5** before **array size is: 5** and as the first operation executed?

Thank you for the help.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "hello";

    std::array<int, 5> vals {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (auto& v: vals) {
        qInfo() << v;
    }
    
    auto* vals_ptr = vals.data();
    qInfo() << *(vals_ptr+1);
    qInfo() << *(vals_ptr+2);

    auto print = [](const int& n) { std::cout << " " << n; };
    std::for_each(vals.cbegin(), vals.cend(), print);
    qInfo() << "array size is: " << vals.size();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output below

```
 1 2 3 4 5hello
1
2
3
4
5
2
3
array size is:  5
```

Comment: The output from `hello` to `array size...` is ok (you have 9 calls to `qInfo`). The only thing I cannot explain is the initial `1 2 3 4 5`. Is that standard input?

Answer (score 4):

From [docs on `qInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInfo):

> Calls the message handler with the informational message message. If no message handler has been installed, the message is printed to stderr. Under Windows, the message is sent to the console, if it is a console application; otherwise, it is sent to the debugger. On QNX the message is sent to slogger2. This function does nothing if QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT was defined during compilation.

In other words, `qInfo` writes to `stderr`. `std::cout` writes to `stdout`. Thats two seperate streams. Only within one stream the output is in order. Due to buffering the streams can be interleaved.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I forgot that qInfo is writing to stderr.

Comment: Changing std::cout to qInfo() fixes the problem. So lesson learnt, do not mix std::cout and the family of functions in qDebug if you want to preserve order.

Answer (score 2):

Different streams have separate buffers and different buffering strategies. If they ultimately output to the same place (i.e. your terminal), and you carelessly mix them, your output is likely to become jumbled, because the moment when any particular buffer buffer is flushed can be unpredictable (or simply inconvenient). To avoid this, use `<< std::flush` each time you are switching streams.

```
qDebug() << "hello" << std::flush; // different stream coming forth
for (auto& v: vals) {
    qInfo() << v; // continuing with qInfo(), no flush here
}
qInfo() << flush; // different stream coming forth
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately in this case flushing or not the order is still jumbled up because they are writing to different streams as answered by @463035818_is_not_a_number. So the fix is consistency.